# Processing.js: p.keyReleased is not a function / simulating keyReleased

Tags: javascript, key, processing, processing.js

I'm making a multiplayer-on-one-keyboard game, which requires me to keep track of multiple keys at the same time. In Processing I did this by creating booleans for the keys I wanted to track, and then using the keyPressed and keyReleased functions to change the booleans.

The problem is that, now when I'm trying to port my processing file to a webpage (using processingjs), it only recognizes keyPressed, while even trying to use keyReleased gives the error in the title.

So my question is, is there any way to make the keyReleased function work in processingjs, or is there a workaround that allows me to simulate keyReleased, even when we go from 3 keys pressed, to 2?

Here's the code that's working for me in processing:

```
void keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == UP) {
    up = true;
  }
if (keyCode == DOWN) {
    down = true;
  }
}

void keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == UP) {
    up = false;
  }
if (keyCode == DOWN) {
    down = false;
  }
}
```

etc. for all 7 keys I'm using

Answer (score 0):

The keyReleased function in the javascript port of Processing seems to work perfectly fine for me. Did you maybe make a mistake in your HTML or Javascript instead?

I have no real knowledge of how Processing should normally work, but this code in HTML/Javascript detects the pressing and releasing of the UP and DOWN key for me and updates the labels below it accordingly (you have to click the canvas first to give it focus).

```
<html>
<script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/processing-js/processing-js/processing-1.4.1.js"></script>
<body>
<script type="application/processing">
var labelUp = document.getElementById("up");
var labelDown = document.getElementById("down");

void setup()
{
  size(200, 200);
}

void keyPressed() 
{
    if (keyCode==UP)
        labelUp.innerHTML="UP: true";
    else if (keyCode==DOWN)
        labelDown.innerHTML="DOWN: true";
}

void keyReleased() 
{
    if (keyCode==UP)
        labelUp.innerHTML="UP: false";
    else if (keyCode==DOWN)
        labelDown.innerHTML="DOWN: false";
}
</script>

<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas><br />

<span id="up">UP: false</span><br />
<span id="down">DOWN: false</span>

</body>
</html>
```